# How do I use `this` in my object literal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im creating a mechanism whereas I can access a given resource (users, posts, etc) through AJAX using jquery, and it works and stuff, BUT I want to be able to use the `this` keyword, instead of for example `Resource.active_filters`, so I would write `this.active_filters` (see code). However, when I use it like that, it refers to the `methods` object instead of the `Resource` object. How do I make it so that it refers to the `Resource` object?

Here is the code:

```
var Resource = {
  options: {},
  active_filters: [],
  ready_filters: [],
  ready_count: 0,
  group_items: [],
  init: function () {},
  methods: {
    reset: function () {
      Resource.active_filters = [];
      Resource.ready_filters = [];
      Resource.ready_count = 0;
    },
  },
  bindEvents: function () {}
};
```

Answer (score 4):

That's how the binding will be unless you define an ES6-style class or define that function at the top-level.

You can always write a classic class:

```
function Resource() {
  // ...
}

Resource.prototype.reset = function() {
  this.active_filters = [ ];
  // ...
}
```

Or you can define an ES6 one:

```
class Resource {
  reset() {
    this.active_filters = [ ];
    // ...
  }
}
```

These two styles are a lot more conventional than the approach in your question.

Comment: I see, and is ES6 supported in all browsers?

Comment: There are no such thing as an "ES6 class". The `class` syntax is merely a syntactic sugar for your first example.

Comment: @M.Mar No, but a common practice would be to transpile your ES6/7+ codes into ES5 compliant codes before deploying.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I've adjusted the terminology here. The [technical definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) is what you're saying, but those  unfamiliar with JavaScript internals might not know the distinction.

Comment: @M.Mar Support is [a little spotty](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) in older browsers, but if you're doing this as a personal experiment or for a newer site with modern users (no significant Internet Explorer share) you shouldn't have many problems. "Transpiling" to ES5 is also an option and is usually easily integrated into your minification pipeline (e.g. [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com)).

Comment: I'm pointing it out because your answer might confuse people to think that there are two types of prototype based classes, while they are actually the same.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Not disagreeing. It's a subtle distinction and a good point.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is some API you are writing that will be invoked by some other code.

When you invoke this API, call `reset` like this:

```
reset.call(Resource)
```

This will call the `reset` function with the `Resource` object's context.

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: i see, cant i also say `methods: { }.call(this)` ?

Comment: No, setting the context of the `reset` function is a _runtime_ concept, not a static one.

Comment: Lets say I have the object literal to load a certain resource, which I want to append to a `<div>` using the synax `$("#users").Resource('users')`. How do I do that?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about that one, could you open up a separate question for that?

Comment: nevermind, i found out, its about making a jquery plugin